# undefined index error in my php script for deleting user

Tags: php

im trying to make a delete user page but I cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

```
Undefined index: bil in C:\wamp\www\FORM\deleteadmin.php on line 4

Undefined index: adminID in C:\wamp\www\FORM\deleteadmin.php on line 5
```

which is line 4 and 5 looks like this,

```
$bil = $_POST['bil'];
$adminID = $_POST['adminID'];
```

the full code are new.php which links to the deleteadmin.php that contains the error.

new.php

```
echo "<form name='update $bil' method=post action=newuser.php>" ?>
    <tr>
        <td><center><?php echo $bil; ?></center></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tel']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
        <td><a href = "deleteadmin.php"><img src="img/deleteicon.png" align="center"></a></td>
        <input type=hidden value={$row['adminID']} name=adminID>
        <input type=hidden value=$bil name=bil>
    </tr>
<?php 
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

deleteadmin.php

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

$bil = $_POST['bil'];
$adminID = $_POST['adminID'];

$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE `adminID`= '$adminID'") or die (mysql_error());

if($result)
{
?>
<script language="javascript">
alert("User No : <?php echo "$bil"; ?> DELETED");
location.href="new.php";
</script>

<?php
}
else
{
?>

<script language="javascript">
alert("User No : <?php echo "$bil"; ?> NOT DELETED");
location.href="new.php";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

What do I need to do to fix them? I've tried using ISSET but it doesnt work. 
I don't understand why this is happening, and I'd love to know how to make it go away.

Comment: 1. You should always surround values in HTML with quotes as a matter of good practice and it sometimes causing problems.
2. How are you submitting this form? I don't see a submit button.

Comment: `action=newuser.php` are you submitting to the right script?

Comment: @esqew no, 'action=newuser.php' is the create new user page

Comment: @jeff what I want to make is when I clicked the 'X' button, the user will be deleted instantly

Comment: Just have the X button fire an AJAX POST call to `deleteadmin.php` with data: `{ "bil" : "1", "adminID", "1" }`. [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) makes this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 problems here

First:

```
<a href = "deleteadmin.php"><img src="img/deleteicon.png" align="center"></a>
```

By clicking this you are only accessing the deleteadmin.php file.
You are not passing any arguments.

Second:

```
$bil = $_POST['bil'];
$adminID = $_POST['adminID'];
```

You are not posting any data so the $_POST variable will be empty.

Solutions

Add query string in the url `?bil=".$bil."&adminID=".$adminID."`

```
<a href = "deleteadmin.php?bil=".$bil."&adminID=".$adminID.""><img src="img/deleteicon.png" align="center"></a>
```

Pass get Values then process in the deleteadmin.php
Instead of using `$_POST` use `$_GET`.

```
$bil = $_GET['bil'];
$adminID = $_GET['adminID'];
```

$_GET[] is used to get the values which are encoded in the query string in the URL.

Then you don't need to have a form for you to delete a user. Just access the deleteadmin.php file passing $_GET values in the url.

Comment: Also in the query

"DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE `adminID`= '$adminID'"

This is not safe. 
To make it more secure always clean user input.
In this case md5 encryption is more than enough

"DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE md5(adminID)= '".md5($adminID)."'"

This helps clean user input. It encrypts the user input so that any unwanted characters will not cause any error or sql injection.

Comment: i did what you suggest, but it still shows error on line 5.

Comment: Check the variables in the link.. They should have exactly the same variable. if you put adminID in the url, in the php you should use $_GET['adminID'] too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are doing is right.. Because, when you click the `<a>` link this will going to give you undefined index errors. So you should pass the parameters as a querystring to your `<a>` .. that is because the `<form>` action points to **newuser.php**

You need to append the parameters , `adminID` and `bil` to this link like this..

```
<td><a href = "deleteadmin.php?adminID=<?php echo $row['adminID']; ?>&bil=<?php echo $bil; ?>"><img src="img/deleteicon.png" align="center"></a></td>
```

and on your `deleteadmin.php` , you need to change from

```
$bil = $_POST['bil'];
$adminID = $_POST['adminID'];
```

to

```
$bil = $_GET['bil'];
$adminID = $_GET['adminID'];
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 2):

this is very easy to fix.

try to do not use hidden and replace your href like this in your new.php:

```
    <td><a href = "deleteadmin.php?adminID={$adminID}&bil={$bil}"><img src="img/deleteicon.png" align="center"></a></td>
```

actually you can replace `$_POST` to become `$_REQUEST` because `$_REQUEST` represent `$_POST` and `$_GET`

hope this can help you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

change code in **new.php** to:

```
echo "<form name='update $bil' method=post action=newuser.php>
    <tr>
        <td><center><?php echo $bil; ?></center></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tel']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
        <td><a href = 'deleteadmin.php'><img src='img/deleteicon.png' align='center'></a></td>
        <input type='hidden' value=$row['adminID'] name='adminID'>
        <input type=hidden value='$bil' name='bil'>
    </tr>
</form>";
```

try this.